# If the human brain is a Turing machine then how is it able to ascertain that certain problems are undecidable?

Tags: turing-machines, computation-models, turing-completeness, neural-computing

I recently read about the idea that the human brain might be a Turing machine (or Turing complete). If that is true then how is the brain able to reason that a certain problem is undecidable for e.g. the [the liar paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liar_paradox). I assume that a Turing machine will nor be able to reason that the liar paradox statement is a logical paradox with no decidable answer and will be stuck forever.

Answer (score 1):

> I assume that a Turing machine will nor be able to reason that the liar paradox statement is a logical paradox with no decidable answer and will be stuck forever.

Why do you assume that? It's perfectly possible for a Turing machine to recognize a specific paradox and to have logic systems that include the concept of paradox.

Also, note that undecidability is a separate concept to paradox. A paradox is a statement that is neither true nor false: it is a property of sentences in formal systems. Undecidability is a property of languages, which are sets of finite strings: specifically the property that there is no Turing machine that correctly determines which strings are in the set and which are not.